# How to find a path to a specific object from a tree of objects?

Tags: c#

I have a "recursive" class like so :

```cs
Class FabElement
{
     List<FabElement> FabElements = new List<FabElement>();

     public FabElement()
     {
     }
}
```

Let say I create an object from this class and call it `FE`. At some point, `FE` will contain a list of `FabElement` and mutiple `FabElement` objects that are identical (reference).

Here's an example of that :

```
FE
     - FE_Children#1
          - FE_Children #4
          - **FE_Children #3** (Let's call it Element A)
     - FE_Children#2
     - **FE_Children #3** (Let's call it Element B)
```

As you can see, FE_Children #3 is at 2 places. I want it to be the same so if I change one, the other one also changes (it's a reference).

At some point, the user might decide to break that "link" and thus create a unique Element B (by doing a Deep Copy for example).

If a function to do receives Element B as a parameter, is there a way to differentiate Element A from Element B by the object itself or I need to pass a second parameter that would be it's full path within the FE object?

Thanks!

Comment: There are not "copies" of the object, there are multiple _references_ to the same object. I don't know if that affects your solution but it may help you think about it a different way. My guess is you'll want to traverse the tree structure until you find the object you are looking for.

Comment: This is what Composite pattern is for. No matter what you do, you should have the node id, node parent id and the the node content can point to the same object from many nodes.

Comment: If the underlying objects are truly the same then what's it matter if you find the one at index 1 or 20?. As @DStanley said, they both reference the same object. When you display the object selected in the tree, technically it will display the same information regardless. _Unless_ they are truly different, in which case why treat them as the same?

Comment: I rewrote the title and picked a duplicate based on a way I read the question. Please check if it aligns with what you are looking for. If you are asking something different than positional path to the object - please [edit] the post with an example data and desired result. Also clarify if you need paths to all or just first/last instance. Also-2 clarify if you expect circles (graph vs. tree) - i.e. if object you are looking for directly includes reference to itself as a child node.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the answers, but my question is not about TreeView. I edited the question and I hope it's clearer.